# Can an Alchemist permanently have a potion buff?

Tags: crafting, alchemist, duration, pathfinder-2e

The Eternal Elixir feat lets an Alchemist make the duration of one of their elixirs "indefinite". The Improbable Elixirs feat lets them craft a magic potion as an elixir.

Can an Alchemist with both these feats make the duration of one of their potions indefinite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes

Eternal elixir lets you take an [infused] [elixir] alchemical item, and make the duration indefinite. Improbable Elixir says you can Craft a number of potions as alchemical items with the [elixir] trait.

So if you just craft them normally with gold, you *cannot* extend the duration to indefinite. But if you use Quick or Advanced Alchemy, they become [infused], and thus meet the parameters for Eternal Elixir.